# Pandas - replace multiple characters from rows in a datframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have addresses stored in "address" column in a store dataframe, I would like to create a new column with the following corrections on existing addresses:

```
{"ST": "STREET",
  "RD": "ROAD",
  "AVE": "AVENUE",
  "N": "NORTH",
  "W": "WEST",
  "S": "SOUTH",
  "E": "EAST",
  "STE": "SUITE",
  "HWY": "HIGHWAY",
  "DR": "DRIVE",
  "NW": "NORTH WEST",
  "NE": "NORTH EAST",
  "SW": "SOUTH WEST",
  "SE": "SOUTH EAST",
  "LN": "LANE",
  "WAY": "WAY"}
```

How should I move forward this?

Expected output:

```
101 ST LN -> 101 STREET LANE
```

Here is the R code to the same:

```
terms <- c("W","WEST","E","EAST","N","NORTH","S","SOUTH")

terms <- split(terms,rep(1:2,times = length(terms) / 2))
terms[[1]] <- paste0("\\b",terms[[1]],"(\\.|\\b|\\,)")
terms[[1]]

stri_replace_all_regex(data$address,pattern = terms[[1]], replacement = terms[[2]],vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) along with the given *regex* `pattern` and replacement function. This *regex* pattern is constructed from the address corrections `mappings` dictionary:

```
pattern =  r'\b(' + '|'.join(mappings.keys()) + r')\b'
df['addr_mapped'] = df['address'].str.replace(pattern, lambda s: mappings.get(s.group()))
```

Example `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': ['101 ST LN', 'foo ST bar WAY', 'bar bar STE', 'W foo WAY STE', 'foo bar']})
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

          address         addr_mapped
0       101 ST LN     101 STREET LANE
1  foo ST bar WAY  foo STREET bar WAY
2     bar bar STE       bar bar SUITE
3   W foo WAY STE  WEST foo WAY SUITE
4         foo bar             foo bar
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more lambda s: d.get(s.group()) function that you have used

Comment: Sure, its a replacement function that takes a regex `matching object` as parameter and returns a replacement value. `s.group()` represent the matching key in the address column, hence we get the replacement using `mappings.get(s.group())`.

Comment: So basically if I understand correctly, I did this to get data from my matchings dictionary

Comment: Yep...@NeerajGrover

Comment: This code works for me

mappings = {"ST":"STREET"}
pattern =  r'\b(' + '|'.join(mappings.keys()) + r')\b'
psstores['store_normal_address'] = psstores['store_address'].str.replace(pattern, lambda s: mappings.get(s.group()))

so I was confused about the 'd' in the lambda function, sorry @shubham-sharma

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, I was using the same mapping dictionary and used the following function. I do not like regex since it is difficult to make business folks understand.

> add_abv is the dictionary you mentioned above

```
def add_abv_rep(string):
str_ex = []
for i in string_ex.split(' '):
    if i in add_abv:
        str_ex.append(add_abv[i])
    else:
        str_ex.append(i)
return ' '.join(y.upper() for y in str_ex)
```

Finally, apply this function to the series.

```
df['Address'] = df['Address'].apply(lambda x: add_abv_rep(x))
```